# Pi and e problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers, pi

I was solving some questions on Math Stack Exchange about irrational numbers when suddenly this question struck me.

We know that $e$ is irrational and that $\pi$ is also irrational.

Then is $\pi\cdot e$ rational or irrational?

Comment: Thats hat ia m asking

Comment: @suomynonA we need to be a little careful since product of two irrationals can be rational.

Comment: When is $\pi^e$ rational? Isn't it always irrational?

Comment: Nobody knows! (But it's likely to be irrational)

Comment: Its an open problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number#Open_questions

Comment: That is the reason behind down votes??

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'd wager those who did believe this question doesn't have sufficient context and doesn't show sufficient effort. "Bare" questions like this one that just ask for information without any context as to why you're asking or some reasoning toward an answer are off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [List of unsolved problems in mathematics - Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics#Analysis) it is yet unknown whether $\pi+e$, $\pi \cdot e$, $\frac{\pi}{e}$ and $\pi^e$ are rational, algebraic irrational, or transcendental.